# Paypal SHA-256 changes, what impact for my IPN?

Tags: php, ssl, paypal, paypal-ipn, sha256

Today I received a mail from Paypal asking me to put my IPN up to date:
With a [Link](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en) to see how to proceed

However my IPN is just something like this:

```
 <?php

    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";


    $header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
    $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com:443\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";


    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
    } else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // process payment
    }
    else if (strcmp (trim($res), "INVALID") == 0) {

//some processes
    }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
    }
    ?>
```

Do I have anything to change?

PS: Since this thread has lot of success, I would like to say that I got all my 3 Paypal accounts blocked because my activity is "too risky" for them... I advise you to make as much as often payment to your bank account, otherwise you could have $4000 blocked like me and after 1 month they just take 3000$ back. Screw Paypal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written on the link given by PayPal, you probably have nothing to change on your code.

But you have to verify that your Server/OS support SHA-2 (SHA-256).

You could find a list of some of them here : [SHA-2 compatibility](https://www.digicert.com/sha-2-compatibility.htm)